# Python Date Index: finding the closest date a year ago from today

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, dataframe

I have a panda dataframe (stock prices) with an index in a date format. It is daily but only for working days.
I basically try to compute some price performance YTD and from a year ago.
To get the first date of the actual year in my dataframe I used the following method:

```
today = str(datetime.date.today())
curr_year = int(today[:4])
curr_month = int(today[5:7])
first_date_year = (df[str(curr_year)].first_valid_index())
```

Now I try to get the closest date a year ago (exactly one year from the last_valid_index()). I could extract the month and the year but then it wouldn't be as precise. Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'a year ago'? 52 weeks, 365 days or 1 year? For comfy date calculations I'd suggest using `arrow` module which offers a [`.shift()` method](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#replace-shift).

Comment: So you're trying to get the closest workday to exactly a year ago? What do you do when there's a holiday on one year but not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any data, I am assuming that you have a list of dates (string types) like the following:

```
dates = ['11/01/2016', '12/01/2016', '02/01/2017', '03/01/2017']
```

You then need to transform that into datetime format, I would suggest using pandas:

```
pd_dates = pd.to_datetime(dates)
```

Then you have to define today and one year ago. I would suggest using datetime for that:

```
today = datetime.today()
date_1yr_ago = datetime(today.year-1, today.month, today.day)
```

Lastly, you slice the date list for dates larger than the date_1yr_ago value and get the first value of that slice:

```
pd_dates[pd_dates > date_1yr_ago][0]
```

This will return the first date that is larger than the 1 year ago date.

**output:**

```
Timestamp('2017-02-01 00:00:00')
```

You can convert that datetime value to string with the following code:

```
datetime.strftime(pd_dates[pd_dates > date_1yr_ago][0], '%Y/%m/%d')
```

**output:**

```
'2017/02/01'
```